# expect().to.have. returns undefined error

Tags: jestjs, enzyme

Per the enzyme docs [here](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/find.html) the following stanza should find a selector by ID:

```
  it('Should render the Select Vehicle entry', () => {
    let component = shallow(<VehicleMenu {...initialState} />);
    expect(component.find("#vehMenuSelect")).to.have.lengthOf(1);
  });
```

But the `.to.have.[...]` method never works for me anywhere in my code, and always returns:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'have' of undefined
```

no matter which selector type I use (in this case find).

This works, and is what I have been using:

```
  it('Should render the Select Vehicle entry', () => {
    let component = shallow(<VehicleMenu {...initialState} />);
    expect(component.find("#vehMenuSelect").length).toBe(1);
  });
```

`.toBe()` always works. Why do I get that error when using the methods described in the current enzyme docs? THis is with `enzyme 3.9.0` and `enzyme-adapter-react-16 1.12.1`.

Comment: It looks like those docs are using [lab](https://github.com/hapijs/lab) for assertions - what are you using for assertions, Jest?

Comment: @Adam is appears the examples use Chai : see the imports in https://airbnb.io/enzyme/

Comment: Huh. That is **not** apparent from the examples... @Adam yes, I am using Jest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example from the docs of enzyme is not using jest. You should follow the docs of jest. Change it to `toHaveLength` instead of `to.have.length`

Comment: Thanks, I typically have both sets of docs open, now I see why they differ on occasion...